# How to set component default props on React component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I use the code below to set default props on a React component but it doesn't work. In the `render()` method, I can see the output "undefined props" was printed on the browser console. How can I define a default value for the component props?

```
export default class AddAddressComponent extends Component {

render() {
   let {provinceList,cityList} = this.props
    if(cityList === undefined || provinceList === undefined){
      console.log('undefined props')
    }
    ...
}

AddAddressComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

AddAddressComponent.defaultProps = {
  cityList: [],
  provinceList: [],
}

AddAddressComponent.propTypes = {
  userInfo: React.PropTypes.object,
  cityList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  provinceList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}
```

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You forgot to close the `Class` bracket.

```js
class AddAddressComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let {provinceList,cityList} = this.props
    if(cityList === undefined || provinceList === undefined){
      console.log('undefined props')
    } else {
      console.log('defined props')
    }

    return (
      <div>rendered</div>
    )
  }
}

AddAddressComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

AddAddressComponent.defaultProps = {
  cityList: [],
  provinceList: [],
};

AddAddressComponent.propTypes = {
  userInfo: React.PropTypes.object,
  cityList: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  provinceList: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <AddAddressComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

Answer (score 102):

For those using something like babel [stage-2](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-2/) or [transform-class-properties](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/):

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';

export default class ExampleComponent extends Component {
   static contextTypes = {
      // some context types
   };

   static propTypes = {
      prop1: PropTypes.object
   };

   static defaultProps = {
      prop1: { foobar: 'foobar' }
   };

   ...

}
```

---

**Update**

As of React v15.5, `PropTypes` was moved out of the main React Package ([link](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

**Edit**

As pointed out by @johndodo, `static` class properties are actually not a part of the ES7 spec, but rather are currently only supported by babel. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: thank for the answer, but i wanted to learn a bit more about it so had a look at `react`/`native` doc and couldn't find them, where is the doc for that?

Comment: I don't think its explicitly in the React docs, but if you understand what `static` class variables are it makes sense, so I suggest reading about them [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static). Basically, the syntax in the documentation is equivalent to this because both are adding information about the props to the class itself, not the individual instances.

Comment: the import is changed to: import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Comment: @treyhakanson The MDN link only talks about static methods, not variables. I couldn't find a reference for static class variables, except for [Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/). Is this an accepted ES7 property?

Answer (score 26):

If you're using a functional component, you can define defaults in the destructuring assignment, like so:

```
export default ({ children, id="menu", side="left", image={menu} }) => {
  ...
};
```

Comment: Kudos for the help, but I think he's asking for the class component.  From personal experience I've find it frustrating from always getting answers relating to the functional component....just saying.

Comment: @GuyPark lol, weird but ok

Comment: how to combine PropTypes.oneOf(['first', 'second', 'third']) with default

Answer (score 17):

First you need to separate your class from the further extensions ex you cannot extend `AddAddressComponent.defaultProps` within the `class` instead move it outside.

I will also recommend you to read about the  [Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) and React's lifecycle: see [Component Specs and Lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)

Here is what you want:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class AddAddressComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let { provinceList, cityList } = this.props;
    if(cityList === undefined || provinceList === undefined){
      console.log('undefined props');
    }
  }
}

AddAddressComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

AddAddressComponent.defaultProps = {
  cityList: [],
  provinceList: [],
};

AddAddressComponent.propTypes = {
  userInfo: PropTypes.object,
  cityList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  provinceList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}

export default AddAddressComponent;
```

Comment: Are you sure they need the `constructor` and `componentWillReceiveProps`? Seems to me the OP just forgot a closing bracket for their class declaration.

Comment: @ivarni not necessarily but it's important he understand the life-cycle, constructor, and the class extensions. so he will know what his doing. so i added few external links

Comment: Fair enough, I just think saying *"you need to"* isn't strictly correct. I'd rather say something along the lines of *"you can add these methods to observe the lifecycle"*. Otherwise, good answer :)

Answer (score 10):

You can also use Destructuring assignment.

```
class AddAddressComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {

    const {
      province="insertDefaultValueHere1",
      city="insertDefaultValueHere2"
    } = this.props

    return (
      <div>{province}</div>
      <div>{city}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

I like this approach as you don't need to write much code.

Comment: The problem I see here is that you might want to use default props in multiple methods.

Answer (score 5):

use a static defaultProps like:

```
export default class AddAddressComponent extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        provinceList: [],
        cityList: []
    }

render() {
   let {provinceList,cityList} = this.props
    if(cityList === undefined || provinceList === undefined){
      console.log('undefined props')
    }
    ...
}

AddAddressComponent.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

AddAddressComponent.defaultProps = {
  cityList: [],
  provinceList: [],
}

AddAddressComponent.propTypes = {
  userInfo: React.PropTypes.object,
  cityList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  provinceList: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
}
```

Taken from:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1772

If you wish to check the types, see how to use PropTypes  in treyhakanson's or Ilan Hasanov's answer, or review the many answers in the above link.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the default props using the class name as shown below.

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

// Specifies the default values for props:
Greeting.defaultProps = {
  name: 'Stranger'
};
```

You can use the React's recommended way from this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values) for more info

Answer (score 4):

For a function type prop you can use the following code:

```
AddAddressComponent.defaultProps = {
    callBackHandler: () => {}
};

AddAddressComponent.propTypes = {
    callBackHandler: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>{this.props.text}</h1>;
  }
}

Example.defaultProps = { text: 'yo' };
```