# React + Flow + eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint, type-safety

I'm trying to get my head around this error entire day. I'm trying to add Flow to my React app.

I have a component declared like this:

```
// @flow
class MyComponent extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    prop1: 'a',
    prop2: 'b'
  };
  handleOnClick: (value: string) => void;
  props: MyComponentProps;
}
```

and type for MyComponentProps

```
type MyComponentProps = {
  prop1: string,
  prop2: string
};
```

Now, Flow is reporting no errors. But when I try to run the app, I get `eslint` errors:

```
 error  'defaultProps' is not defined   no-undef
 error  'handleOnClick' is not defined  no-undef
 error  'props' is not defined          no-undef
```

I'm using `babel-eslint` and [eslint-plugin-flowtype](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype).
I've added `flowtype/define-flow-type` rule to my `.eslintrc` file. Here's the relevant portion of my `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype",
    "react"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "flowtype/define-flow-type": 1,
    "flowtype/use-flow-type" : 1,
    "no-undef": 2,
    "react/jsx-no-undef": 2
   }}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you getting those ESLint errors on the declarations, or somewhere you're referencing them?

Comment: On the declarations.

Comment: What versions of eslint, babel-eslint, and eslint-plugin-flowtype do you have?

Answer (score 1):

did you import React using `import React from 'react'` ?

Comment: Yes :) This is a working component, I am just trying to add type safety to it.

Comment: props  ` props: MyComponentProps;` --> this is one of the complaints
it doesn't know where it it declared. If this is a component then you would need to use propTypes or contextTypes. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786973/how-to-set-component-default-props-on-react-component

Check out this post. Please ask if you have additional questions.

Comment: the handler should be declared like a function within the class that you are trying to export. it should be `handleClick() {}`

You are also missing a semicolon at the end of the class you are exporting.

Comment: I think you missed the point. I'm trying to add Flow to the component, and I believe I'm doing that correctly. I don't want `propTypes`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error you receive is that lint is unable to detect your environment.

You can edit in ".eslintrc.json" file as follows.

```
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true
},
```

Or

```
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 6
```

},

For more detailed information : https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef

Comment: please elaborate buddy, and don't provide opinions as answers(*I think* or *I guess*, etc.)