# Is it a valid way to set default props from this.props in React?

Tags: reactjs

I need to set up default property for MyComponent when my component first time render. I receive value from the back end service. Is it a valid way to set up default props using value from this.props?

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        const {
            myProperty= {},
        } = this.props

        return (
            <SimpleComboBoxControl
                value={myProperty.myProperty_function_type}
            />
        )
    }
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    myProperty: {
        myProperty_function_type: this.props.myInitialProperty,
    },
}
MyComponent.displayName = 'MyComponent '
MyComponent.propTypes = propTypes

export default MyComponent
```

Comment: I think this will be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786973/how-to-set-component-default-props-on-react-component

Answer (score 0):

As per React's standard, the props sent to a child should not be mutated as they might be referenced by other components and data propagation from child to parent is through accessing the parent method, hence whatever you are doing is not advised.

You can set default state of your parent component and can pass the state as a Props to the child component. Once you receive the data from an API/backend service you can update the state in componentWillReceiveProps.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({ yourStateObj: 'nextProps' });
}
```

`<CustomComponent yourPropData={this.yourStateObj}/>`

In Case you are using React and Redux you can `setInitialState` in reducer and can be utilised in your parent component using `mapStateToProps` and then pass it as a props to the component.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're suggesting is NOT illegal but it's not recommended to do it like that. If you need to mutate your `prop` just after rendering the component, I suggest you do the following (using `state`):

**MyComponent:**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
    state = {
      myProperty: {}
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      // Here you can put your Backend call to receive the data
      // After getting the data you just need to update the state
      this.setState({ myProperty: backendResult });
    }

    render() {
        const { myProperty } = this.state;

        return (
            <SimpleComboBoxControl
                value={myProperty.myProperty_function_type}
            />
        )
    }
}

MyComponent.displayName = 'MyComponent ';
MyComponent.propTypes = propTypes;

export default MyComponent;
```

This way, you'll be sure that every time the component renders, you'll ask for the Backend information and store it in the state we just define. If you want to be extra sure, you could use lodash's [isEmpty](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEmpty) method to check if the Backend call really has data.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with the @AlbertoPerez, still if your particular component is not re-rendering then I think your code is valid. Below is the simple working demo on the basis of your code. I hope that will be helful.

```js
// import React, { useState } from 'react';

const SimpleComboBoxControl = (props) => {
    return (<div>{props.value}</div>)
}

class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        const {
            myProperty = {},
            myInitialProperty = {}
        } = this.props

        return (
            <SimpleComboBoxControl
                value={myProperty.myProperty_function_type}
            />
        )
    }
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    myProperty: {
        myProperty_function_type: 'MyInitialProperty value or a data from API call.',
    },
}

MyComponent.displayName = 'MyComponent';

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent myInitialProperty='Test' />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Thanks, Jignesh Raval